# Segfault in C++ merge sort code

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

Trying to get this to work.. GDB seems to indicate that the indexes might be off for some reason. I'm using a vector of a subclass called Record containing mainly population (int) and name (string) that needs to be sorted both ways. bt indicates null pointer at line 27 which is the 'if' statement in the isSmaller() function. This function works perfectly well with an insertion sort code in the same program, but not the merge sort, so I'm wondering what's wrong with the merge sort code. Please advise. Is something wrong with the algorithm?

bt returns the following:

```
#0  0x0000000000403160 in CensusData::isSmaller (this=0x7fffffffdd10, type=0,     r1=0x609590, r2=0x0) at CensusDataSorts.cpp:27
#1  0x0000000000403510 in CensusData::mergeIt (this=0x7fffffffdd10, type=0,     list=..., p=0, q=1, r=2) at CensusDataSorts.cpp:96
#2  0x0000000000403347 in CensusData::mergeSortIt (this=0x7fffffffdd10,     type=0, list=..., p=0, r=2) at CensusDataSorts.cpp:70
#3  0x0000000000403645 in CensusData::mergeSort (this=0x7fffffffdd10, type=0)    at CensusDataSorts.cpp:113
#4  0x0000000000401a50 in runMergeSorts (fp=...) at CensusSort.cpp:106
#5  0x0000000000401e6f in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe068)    at CensusSort.cpp:174
```

Code appears below

```
bool CensusData::isSmaller(int type, Record* r1, Record* r2)
{
    if(type==POPULATION)
    {
        if(r1->population <= r2->population)
            return true;
    }

    else if(type==NAME)
    {
        if(*(r1->city) <= *(r2->city))
            return true;
    }

    return false;        
}

void CensusData::mergeSortIt(int type, vector<Record*>& list, int p, int r)
{
    if(p < r)
    {
        int q = floor((p+r)/2);
        mergeSortIt(type,list,p,q);
        mergeSortIt(type,list,q+1,r);
        mergeIt(type,list,p,q,r);
    }        
}    

void CensusData::mergeIt(int type, vector<Record*>& list, int p, int q, int r)
{
    int n1=q-p+1;
    int n2=r-q;
    int i,j;

    vector<Record*> L(n1,0);
    vector<Record*> R(n2,0);

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++)
        L[i]=list[p+i];

    for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
        R[j]=list[q+j+1];

    i=0;
    j=0;

    for(int k=p; k<=r; k++)
    {
        if(isSmaller(type,L[i],R[j]))
        {
            list[k]=L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            list[k]=R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void CensusData::mergeSort(int type)
{
    mergeSortIt(type, data, 0, data.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: As you are already debugging in GDB, mind giving us the function call backtrace? And please point out where in the shown code the crash happens. Also please add the sizes of the vectors involved as well as the indexes when the crash happens.

Comment: You mean type bt in GDB and post output?

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000403160 in CensusData::isSmaller (this=0x7fffffffdd10, type=0, 
    r1=0x609590, r2=0x0) at CensusDataSorts.cpp:27
27   if(r1->population <= r2->population)

Comment: I'm using the size() function where needed to fetch the vector size since they're being populated from a csv file. OP appended.

Comment: Yes, the output from the `bt` command. And please *edit your question* to include it.

Comment: The best way to solve these kind of problems is to use a smaller set of data, and then step through the code, line by line, while watching variables and indexes.

Comment: The test data size is 3. How do I 'step' ?

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but you should know regardless: *never* have a hard "always-value" (in this case `return false;`) in a sorting comparator; *ever*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the way you rewrite merged records:

```
for(int k=p; k<=r; k++)
{
    // Here i or j can be outside L/R bounds
    if(isSmaller(type,L[i],R[j]))
    {
        list[k]=L[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        list[k]=R[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

here is rewritten version:

```
int k=p;
for(; k<=r; k++)
{
    if(isSmaller(type,L[i],R[j]))
    {
        list[k]=L[i];
        i++;
        if ( i == L.size() )
          break;
    }
    else
    {
        list[k]=R[j];
        j++;
        if ( j == R.size() )
          break;
    }
}
for ( ; i < L.size(); ++i )
  list[k++]=L[i];
for ( ; j < R.size(); ++j )
  list[k++]=R[j];
```

I am not sure if this makes your program work as intended, but it should fix your segfault.

Comment: It gave me some progress and I made a slight change in your new code... instead of list[k++] for the last 2 loops, I used list[++k] and it now WORKS FLAWLESSLY! Thank you xD

Answer (score 0):

r2=0x0) at CensusDataSorts.cpp:27, i.e. you have a null pointer.

Also change comparison to:

```
return r1->population < r2->population;
```

and

```
return *(r1->city) < *(r2->city);
```

Otherwise it does not make sense. You cannot have <= for it to be logically correct. In fact I have myself got sorting crashes due to improper comparisons.

Comment: Line 27 is simple the if condition from the code above from function isSmaller():

  if(r1->population <= r2->population)

Comment: Yes either you need to guard against r2 being null pointer or you need to initialize the pointer r2 properly. Sorry for short answer above.

Comment: The exact same isSmaller() function works perfectly fine with an insertion sort code in the same program. So I'm wondering what's wrong with the merge sort code..

Comment: Tried it... still the same issue. The problem seems to lie in the last for loop within mergeIt() which if I comment, the code runs fine (without sorting the data ofcourse). I could be wrong though as the bounds of the indexes for the vectors may be off before said loop.

Comment: I agree that the most likely cause is the vector sorted not being healthy.